# Browser issue with ASP.net Standard Control Button

Tags: asp.net

how can fix the bugs of button which look's  different in two different browser(IE,MOZILLA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply CSS styles to the input element to make it ignore any browser/operating system looks.

Here's a simple example, this should appear in your `head` element:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #btn { border: solid 1px #693ace; background-color: #cecece; color: #ffffff; }
</style>
```

And the button's HTML:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Styled button" />
```

[This site](http://www.webreference.com/programming/css_stylish/) has some good examples.

Comment: i face alot of problem with cross browser problem.thus  this is helpful for me i think

Answer (score 2):

You can't unless you use an image for the button.

You are asking something similar to making your applicaiton loko the same on XP and Windows 7 - there are certain things you can't change without breaking the standard control contracts.

Comment: I assume you want the buttons to look *exactly* the same in both browsers.  And they won't because the browsers have their own opinion of what a button is.  It just has to act the same way, not look the same.  If this isn't what you mean, change your question to say what you mean.

Comment: ya this time u r rt. how can i fix it pls help me.

Comment: You can't.  If you want another analogy, it's like trying to make 2 cars look the same because they're both supposed to be cars.  It won't happen.